# How to create a MS-Word file using PHP?

Tags: php, ms-word

I need to create a word file probably from a database table in PHP, is there any class available for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [Microsoft Office XML formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Word_XML_Format_example)
So you can use it to create a word file.

Answer (score 0):

Searched for rtf class generator on google for php and this was the first find

[RTF PHP class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1805-PHP-Create-RTF-documents-from-HTML.html)